# Why do we need TCP and SSL load balancers in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud has HTTP(S) load balancers, Network (TCP/UDP) load balancers, SSL proxy and TCP proxy load balancers.

I have a few queries regarding the TCP load balancers:

- What happens when HTTP traffic hits a TCP load balancer? Now i understand that the TCP protocol is layer 4 of the OSI model. So does this mean that the load balancer only looks at TCP packets and forwards them. And if yes, why is that important?
- What would be the use case of having just a TCP load balancer serving as a reverse proxy? Wouldn't one need to have a TCP load balancer along with an HTTP(S) load balancer configuration in order to route the traffic intelligently to the backends? If yes, why do we need a TCP load balancer?

I have the same set of queries for SSL proxy load balancers? Why do we need them in addition to an HTTPS load balancer?

Comment: Google has a document that compares the different types of load balancers and a decision tree to help you select: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for leading me to this. But what happens when traffic is routed from a L4 load balancer to a L7 load balancer. When a user sends an HTTP request would the L4-lb simply inspect the TCP data of the request and forward them along with its L7 data to the backends?

Comment: A layer 4 load balancer does not inspect layer 7 data. Load balancers make routing decisions, they do not usually modify data. Therefore the TCP packet would be forwarded to the layer 7 load balancer.

Comment: @Nosail, was your question already addressed? If so, please post it as an answer so other community members with similar questions will find this helpful.

Comment: I guess I am trying to understand what would be the use case of TCP and SSL load balancer? Why can't an HTTPS load balancer do what TCP and SSL load balancers are doing.